# Ciclo for, cómo hago para que los resultados sean en un data frame? Rstudio

Tags: r, bucle-for, bucles, rstudio

tengo que hacer esta función 10 veces con atributos diferentes que estan almacenados en una lista,
pero al hacer el ciclo for, el resultado que me arroja es una lista, pero lo que necesito es obtener 10 data frame con cada resultado para cada atributo que va seleccionando i.

```
recprueba <- c()

for (i in 1:length(atributos)) {
 recprueba [i] <- subset(getPairs(epiWeights(RLBigDataDedup(muestra
                                                           , strcmp    = atributos[[i]]
                                                           , strcmpfun = "jarowinkler"
                                                           , exclude   = c(var_excluidas, "cedula", "yy_hecho", "mm_hecho", "dept_hecho", "dd_hecho")))
                                 ,single.rows = TRUE), Weight >= .7)
}
```

Muchas gracias si alguien me puede ayudar ya que  no soy muy buena con los ciclos

Comment: Seguramente ya tienes 10  `data.frames` pero en una lista, cada uno lo puedes referenciar como `recprueba[[1]]` por ejemplo. ¿que buscas realmente?

Comment: Si señor, finalmente me di cuenta de eso, muchas gracias!